# pandas matching row by grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to match value through index by group?  What I mean is this:

For example, I have this df:

```
 Id   Rank   Name   
 111  7       x      
 111  5       y      
 111  1       z      
 222  1       x      
 333  5       a     
 333  1       b      
 444  1       c
```

I want to add a column in to my df:  (group by id, match then name based on its rank)

```
 Id   Rank   Name   New Col
 111  7       x      x
 111  5       y      y-x
 111  1       z      z-x
 222  1       x      x
 333  5       a      a
 333  1       b      b-a
 444  1       c      c
```

Comment: There is no code to correct on your post, am I right ? I'm learning pandas, and I'd like to know how you got there, to understand the solution that might be given.

Comment: @IMCoins I only have the logic down but in term of the code, I don't know how to write that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with `groupby` + `first`, and then use `np.where` to decide where to apply the changes.

```
i = df.groupby('Id').Name.transform('first')    
df['New Col'] = np.where(np.equal(df.Name, i), df.Name, df.Name + '-' + i)

df
    Id  Rank Name New Col
0  111     7    x       x
1  111     5    y     y-x
2  111     1    z     z-x
3  222     1    x       x
4  333     5    a       a
5  333     1    b     b-a
6  444     1    c       c
```

Comment: Worked like a charm like always :))
Just out of curiosity, how different would the code be if I want to match it by the following value instead of the top?
For example, for id = 111 New Col would be x, y-x, and z-y instead of z-x.

Comment: @TylerNG You're welcome. As for your other question, hmm, it'll require a different answer. Give me a bit of time if you want it. You could also open a new question and I'll answer you there.

Comment: @TylerNG Alright, here it is: `(df.Name + '-' + df.groupby('Id').Name.shift().fillna('')).str.rstrip('-')`